# Converting a timestamp to a relative date/time (e.g., "2 minutes ago") and continuously updating it with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Does anybody know how did Facebook do that "time ago". I'm trying to do the same with PHP/Javascript

I think it works something like PHP renders timestamp in HTML and then Javascript continuously calculate the time ago; does anybody know any more info about this?

[image: Example of a timestamp formatted as "2 minutes ago"]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**http://timeago.yarp.com/**

This is a great [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin for it, and it explains the concept quite concisely.

Comment: +1. This is better than any possible PHP solution because it updates automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another fully-customizable alternative:
https://github.com/layam/js_humanized_time_span