# How to define distance in time in words in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to include very common feature in my web application. I would like the times/dates be written as the distance of time from now in words, for example (2 hours ago).

Rails have excellent implementation of this functionality, but I need something like that written in pure javascript. The problem is, that lots of pages in my application are cached, and the only thing that would change is the actual time.

Are there any extended libraries in JS which could translate a date to a distance of time in words?

Comment: If the time is coming from the server, pay attention to issues like different time zones otherwise people will see "-2 hours ago".

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614032/how-did-facebook-do-time-ago

Comment: @Shadow Wizard For timeago (and I'd assume other similar libraries) as long as the date is UTC or contains the timezone it should use the timezone of the user (as reported by the browser).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin for jQuery works well.

From the example code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
```

*Since you referenced using libraries, I'm assuming 'pure javascript' just means not anything on the server.*

Comment: Yes, bad framing. I want to aviod pulling anything from the server, aside from the cached page.

Comment: Timeago works fine, but breaks is you use it in an embedded iframe

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use [JavaScript Relative Time Helpers](https://github.com/jherdman/javascript-relative-time-helpers). It's an extension of the `Date` class, providing a handy `toRelativeTime()` method.